# Outlook Rules: Exact Subject Line Match

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, rules

I'm trying to set up a rule in Outlook that will seek emails that contain an **exact** match in the subject line.

For example, I would want this rule to apply only to emails with a subject line of "Hi there" and not "Hi there Charlene" or "blah blah blah Hi there".

Right now, it seems like Outlook will parse the subject line and determine whether it contains the string. I need it to seek only an exact match.

Outlook 2016, btw. Has anybody got any input? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This applies to exchange mailflow rules (exchange admin center in 365).  I don't know if it applies to user rules in Outlook.

Use "Subject matches these text patterns"

For pattern add `^` at the beginning of your text and `$` at the end of your text.  `^` specifies the text must be at the beginning of the entire string.  `$` specifies the text must be at the end of the entire string.  This ensures the entire subject string matches your specified text.  You may need to enter in all the case variants you want to match.

Example rule: `^Hi there$`

Result: matches `Hi there` but not `Hi there recipient` or `I wanted to say Hi there`

For more information about using regular expression see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/regular-expressions-usage-transport-rules

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can do that using the "Advanced Find" tool. Click to the search box above messages and use the "Search Tools -> Advanced Find" on "Search" ribbon tab to open the Advanced Find dialog. On the dialog, select the "Advanced" tab. Now click the "Field" button and select the "All Mail Fields -> Subject", select the "is (exactly) as a condition and specify required full subject as a value. Now click "Add to List" button and then "Find Now".

Comment: This is wrong answer. OP is asking about the rule and your answer is about search